# Windows 10 Stuck on "Restart" Screen

Tags: windows-10, reboot, hp-laptop

This morning when I woke up, I opened my new win10 laptop to find that it was stuck on the restart screen. I waited for an hour and a half, but it's still stuck. I left it on for the night (closed, in sleep mode), so i dont know what happened to it. Nothing abnormal happened when I last used it and I used it for my normal uses. I also know that Windows 10 had an update that I've been putting off for a few days.

My laptop is an HP Red Flyer with 4 GB of RAM, an Intel Pentium CPU, and a 500 GB SSD. I don't know what drivers I have, as I didn't install any. What should I do?

I know other questions like this exist, but I don't think this relates to them (Except for the whole restarting thing).

Comment: If its been more then a day, then its stuck attempting to do something, and you should power down the laptop at this point.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, that worked! It booted up a bit slow, but it's working like normal now.

Comment: Mine almost always get stuck at restarting. Any solution?